# Teleport script not working as intended

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to make a gameobject in my game, which when enter trigger, then it will teleport my character to an another position (otherTeleport.transform.position), however when I use the script what I have written, my character won't teleport there, while the enemy will. If I put a Debug.Log in the bounce script which will log the character's position I see that my character has been at the otherTeleport's position, but only for one debuglog, and after that it's back to the original teleport's position. The teleport's would be working two-way so if the user go to one it will port it to the second, and if he goes to the second, then it will be ported to the first.

Here is my code:

```c#
public class TeleportScript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject otherTeleport;
private Collider otherTeleportColl;

public bool isNeedToTeleport;
private TeleportScript otherTeleportScript;
private GameObject player;
private Bounce bounceScript;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    isNeedToTeleport = true;
    otherTeleportColl = otherTeleport.GetComponent<Collider>();
    otherTeleportScript = otherTeleport.GetComponent<TeleportScript>();
    player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    bounceScript = player.GetComponent<Bounce>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) {

    if (isNeedToTeleport == true) {
        if (collider.tag == "Enemy") {
            otherTeleportScript.setNeedToTeleport(false);
            collider.transform.position = otherTeleport.transform.position;

        }
        if (collider.tag == "Player") {

            otherTeleportScript.setNeedToTeleport(false);
            bounceScript.player.transform.position = otherTeleport.transform.position;
            collider.transform.position = otherTeleport.transform.position;
            bounceScript.playerTransform.position = otherTeleport.transform.position;


        }


    }


}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider) {
    Debug.Log ("TELEPORTED OUT");
    setNeedToTeleport(true);
    otherTeleportScript.setNeedToTeleport(true);
}


public void setNeedToTeleport(bool value) {
    if (value == true) {
        isNeedToTeleport = true;
    }
    else {
        isNeedToTeleport = false;
    }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My guess for your issue would be the logic behind the teleportation. If your player triggers the teleport trigger on TeleporterA it will teleport to TeleporterB. Your player will then trigger the teleport trigger on TeleporterB and teleport to TeleporterA. See the issue here? You may want to set a cooldown timer so you aren't constantly teleporting every time your player enters the teleport trigger. There are a few other ways to solve this issue but they can get messy with layers etc. I highly doubt someone will write your script for you so you may have to figure the logic out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes to your code, can't test it because I don't have access to unity right now, let me know if it works...

```c#
public class TeleportScript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject otherTeleport;
private Collider otherTeleportColl;

public bool isNeedToTeleport;
private TeleportScript otherTeleportScript;
private GameObject player;
private Bounce bounceScript;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    isNeedToTeleport = true;
    otherTeleportColl = otherTeleport.GetComponent<Collider>();
    otherTeleportScript = otherTeleport.GetComponent<TeleportScript>();
    player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    bounceScript = player.GetComponent<Bounce>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) {

    if(collider.tag == "Player" && isNeedToTeleport)
    {
            otherTeleportScript.setNeedToTeleport(false);
            collider.transform.position = otherTeleport.transform.position;
            bounceScript.player.transform.position = otherTeleport.transform.position; //not sure what is this for....
    }

}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider) {
    Debug.Log ("TELEPORTED OUT");
    setNeedToTeleport(true);
    otherTeleportScript.setNeedToTeleport(true);
}


public void setNeedToTeleport(bool value) {
    if (value == true) 
        isNeedToTeleport = true;  
    else 
        isNeedToTeleport = false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your character teleports to the other place
- after that you move the collider over there aswell, **notice** that the collider's object of other script of teleportation has been initialized with the  **isNeedToTeleport = true;**
- The character now also bounces there, hits the collider of the other object, it checks that **isNeedToTelport is in fact tru**e in this other script and it goes into the same If condition and teleports back!

Answer (score 1):

Take this line:

```c#
otherTeleportScript.setNeedToTeleport(true);
```

out of your OnTriggerExit, or set it to false. Actually setting it to false might be better. You want to tell the other script that someone is incoming and it shouldn't immediately teleport them back.

As an aside, you should change your setNeedToTeleport function to this:

```c#
public void setNeedToTeleport(bool value) {
        isNeedToTeleport = value;
}
```

Those ifs are redundant.

Comment: Agree about the `ifs` being redundant, i would go as far to say the whole function is redundant.